# "node_modules" folder unnecessarily large?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

When using `npx create-react-app`, it creates a `node-modules` folder of over 150 mb. I obviously don't want this large folder to be created every single time I make a new React application, so I wanted to know if there is any way to use React without this problem.

I tried doing `rm -rf ./node-modules` and then `npm i` but it just re-creates the folder with the same size.

[image]

Comment: Create React App is **not** a requirement for using React. If you don't need all of the functionality it provides and don't want all of the dependencies it installs, _don't use it_.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer you cannot use anything in the javascript ecosystem without a **node_modules** folder unless you use a CDN for the packages you want to have.

**What node_modules is ?**

It serves as a cache for your external dependencies that are pulled ( downloaded ) from npm registry.

Therefor the more dependencies your application has the bigger the node_modules folder is.